# Spring WS retry mechanism on HTTP errors

Tags: spring-ws

We are using Spring-WS for SOAP communication, and would need to implement a retry mechanism in case of certain HTTP errors. For instance when receiving an HTTP 503 during an outgoing SOAP call, we would need a strategy to retry the call, e.g. with exponential backoff.

Does Spring-WS provide out of the box some retry strategy implementations? If not, what is the best practice to implement a custom one?

Comment: it's not exactly out of the box, since there is some "configuration" to be done...
I'll remand you to this url for the LONG explanation. 
I won't take credit for it by answering since i'd link the article on a blog anyway.
http://xpadro.blogspot.it/2013/12/retry-web-service-operations-with.html
Suffice to say the core of the article is the integration of spring integration with the webservice call, once that is covered the only missing piece of the link is the definition of the retryadvice bean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have never heard about Spring Retry. It looks promising so far, but we need to learn more about it. Our first idea was to use the retry features of Apache Httpclient, but faced some conflicts with Spring WS.